# Setting __proto__ to null and then re-setting it breaks instanceof in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

I came across some odd behaviour while messing around in JavaScript

```
function Class() {};
var a = {};

a.__proto__ = Class.prototype
a instanceof Class => true
```

Setting proto to null, and then re-assigning it the same value makes the instanceof operator return false rather than true.

```
a.__proto__ = null
a.__proto__ = Class.prototype
a instanceof Class => false
```

Comment: Are you pointing out what you think is a bug, or do you have an actual question? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

I'm directing your attention to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in obj.**proto** = ... statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered. If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

And

> Warning: While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 6 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers. For better support, it is recommended that only Object.getPrototypeOf() be used instead.

In short, you're breaking things and then asking why they're broken. `__proto__` isn't meant to be altered, and there isn't a standardized behaviour, so you can't depend on it doing what you want.

What are you trying to do? What is your end goal?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and was learning about the new operator. I think what I was trying to do here was figure out what specifically makes an object an instance of something.

Comment: I would recommend looking at docs for [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) then.

Answer (score -1):

[![2 protos][1]][1]

Although i'm not sure why you'd do any of this, the inspector shows that the object has two **proto** properties. That is also an oddity, considering that property names should be unique. If you want somewhat of a semi explanation (non explanation), the two **proto** properties mess with instanceOf